# Web forms stopped remembering previously entered values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have one question regarding browser remembering previously entered values... I'm developing ASP.NET MVC 2 application and for some reason my web site suddenly stopped remembering previously entered values in text inputs. I can still see values entered yesterday, but non from today.

I also noticed that my username textbox values started appearing in email textbox although I never changed the name or id of my html elements. The only thing I did was to remove some input elements and added some new... But they all have unique id's and names...

I did a lot of search over the web, but just couldn't find the right answer...

Would it be possible that the model binding could be causing this which I implemented today? Or maybe some web.config configuration?

Is there any reasonable explanation on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by deleting all IE temporary files. Sounds more like browser issue than code issue..

Answer (score 0):

OK... Issue resolved... The problem was that on my form a had a button whose type was set to 'button' instead of 'submit'... I was posting data with ajax. When I changed button type back to 'submit' and updated my javascript function to return false after executing ajax, everything worked as it should and my submitted values begun appearing in my input elements as suggestions when double clicked on input element.